# How can i change locale

Tags: flutter

I want to translate showDatePicker labels i can change cancelText, congirmText and helpText with paramater.Theoretically, when I change the locale parameter to Locale ('tr'), the dates should be translated to Turkish dates, but this gives an error.
Locale('en') while not giving error Locale('tr') gives an error. I checked Tr in supported langs.
Is there any way to use Locale('tr')?

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building
> _DatePickerDialog(dirty, dependencies: [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#b2e0e], _InheritedTheme, MediaQuery],
> state: _DatePickerDialogState#4c7b9): The method 'formatMediumDate'
> was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling:
> formatMediumDate(Instance of 'DateTime')

```
                          showDatePicker(
                            cancelText: proTranslate["Back"][Language.languageIndex],
                            confirmText: proTranslate["Okay"][Language.languageIndex],
                            helpText: Language.languageIndex == 1 ? proTranslate["TARİH SEÇ"]:"TARİH SEÇ",
                            context: context,
                            locale: Locale('en',''),
                            initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                            firstDate: DateTime.now(),
                            lastDate: DateTime(2025),
                          ).then((value) {
                            setState(() {
                              try {
                                _selectedDate = value.year.toString() +
                                    "-" +
                                    ((value.month.toString().length == 1)
                                        ? ("0" + value.month.toString())
                                        : value.month.toString()) +
                                    "-" +
                                    (value.day.toString().length == 1
                                        ? "0" + value.day.toString()
                                        : value.day.toString());
                              } catch (e) {
                                print("[ERROR] [ADDEVENT] [showDatePicker] $e");
                              }
                            });
                          })
```

Visiually i want to change Sunday,September etc.. their Turkish equivalents.

[image]

With this problem i have another similar problem i cant write Locale('tr-en...') in supportedLocales its gives an error too

> Compiler message: lib/pages/mainmenu.dart:50:21: Error: The class
> 'Locale' is abstract and can't be instantiated. Locale('en','US'),

```
 return MaterialApp(
                  supportedLocales: [
                    Locale('en','US'), // the error appears here
                  ],
                  localizationsDelegates: [
                    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
                  ],
                  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                  theme: theme,
                  home: MainMenuBody(
                    warning: snapshot.data[0].warning,
                  ),
                  // navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

All problems were solved, by deleting only supportedLocales in MaterialApp.